# mod_rewrite one condition two rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one condition with two different rules. I cannot merge them. In my code, only the first one works and the second one is ignored:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ termitin.php?cat=$1&lang=$2&word=$3    [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ result.php?source=$1&target=$2&q=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `L` in the `[]` means **LAST** rule. e.g. stop processing and go to the specified url immediately.

Comment: I made the first one [QSA, NC] and removed [L] but still the second one does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This condition is wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !-d
```

Correct syntax is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

which means execute rewrite if request is not for a directory.

Besides that your **main problem** is that you're using same matching pattern and same condition in both rules:

```
^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$
```

You need to define your requirement clearly like under what conditions which script will execute.

Comment: I replaced them with your suggested syntax, the same problem. Only the first one works and the second one does not work. I need to merge them.

Comment: Go through my edited answer again. You need to define your requirement clearly

Comment: I need to search 2 pages: termitin.php and also result.php and both of them have the same structure with different results: termitin.php gives something like Chemistry/en/test and result.php gives en/de/test General dictionary and technical dictionary.

Comment: That can't be done since matching pattern is exactly different. e.g. You my need to put a prefix before result like: `result/en/de/test`

Comment: With this change both of them work but I need those two lines. Is not there any way?

Comment: As I said You can't have exactly same pattern for 2 different rewrites.